# Using Cell Address With "=" In VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write code to find a find a range with a user inputted value and link the value next to it in another cell using the cell address.  I want to be able to update the original cell, and have the linked one follow like you would if you put "=$A$1" just using regular excel.

I tried using 'MyRange = "=" & RangeFound' and it gives me an error.

I tried changing the cell type to text by using 'MyRange.NumberFormat = "@"' but that results in the cell displaying '=$A$1' as text instead of linking to the cell like I want.

There is probably a simple fix to this such as using a different method(?) than .Address or something similar, I just don't know where to find it.

Here is the full code I have used to far that gives the cell address and not the linked value:

```
Sub AutoPaste4()

Dim rng As Range
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim rngGiven As Range

    Set rngGiven = Application.InputBox("Select a part number", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
   
    Set rngFound = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells.Find(rngGiven)
    If rngFound Is Nothing Then End
    
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select where to paste number", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
    
    rng.FormulaR1C1 = rngFound.Offset(, 1).Address
 
End Sub
```

Comment: `.FormulaR1C1` should be `.Formula`, and you're missing an `=`.

Comment: Hi BigBen, 

I changed .FormulaR1C1 to .Formula but that still does not give me what I am looking for.

Can you clarify where I am missing an = ?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: `rng.Formula = "=" & rngFound.Offset(, 1).Address`?

Comment: Got it, thanks!  Works like I want now.  I'll look into what the difference between .formula and .formulaR1C1 is.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=a1+vs+r1c1+excel

Answer (score 0):

Provided by BigBen.

Change
rng.FormulaR1C1 = rngFound.Offset(, 1).Address
to
rng.Formula = "=" & rngFound.Offset(, 1).Address